# How to place "window.location.href" in HTML Link

Tags: javascript, php

My Script:

```
 <script language="javascript">
        function emailCurrentPage() {
            window.location.href = "mailto:?subject=" + document.title + "&body="+ encodeURI(document.location);
        }
    </script>

<button onclick="emailCurrentPage()">Email page</button>
```

Creates email with URL and Variables in Email Body as text

Example:

```
http://example.com/?Price=250&Color=Red**
```

Want to make as HREF link

```
<a href="example.com/?Price=250&Color=Red/" target="_top">Your Order</a>
```

Help?

Comment: You need to describe it definitely better, currently, it's just... unclear.

Comment: What you seem to be describing is what is done by a plain mailto link: `<a href="mailto:?subject-etc-etc">Email page</a>` — that is to say, you don't need a button with javascript to do this. You could style the `<a>...</a>` to _look_ like a button, and/or put `<button>...</button>` around the `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `a` element on the fly such as:

```js
const linkElement = document.createElement("a");

linkElement.href="yourURL"; // your own logic
linkElement.target="_top";
linkElement.text="Your Order"

document.body.append(linkElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='example.com/?Price=250&Color=Red/'">Email page</button>
```

Comment: Need to be a dynamic url